# Not all independent variables available for same time period..how to handle such situations for ML models?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, dataset

I have 9/10 independent variables for which information is available for last 2 years (including dependent variable). For 1/10 variables the information is only available for last 2 months as this feature was recently launched. The simplest way would be to build a model on 2 months for which all variables are available, but number of data points are not enough.

Is there a way I can incorporate the new feature in model i.e. using 2 months data, but for other 9/10 features I still build model using 2 years of data?

Comment: What is your prediction length?

Comment: Please tell us more of the context and which kind of model you will be using. Time series? Maybe, using the complete 2 month dataset, build a model predicting the new features, and then using that model to impute those features on the earlier data? might be troublesome if there is nonstationarity or some concept drift or ...

Comment: Its a binary classification model....the overall objective is to predict customer satisfaction (yes/no) for an article read based on some reading behavior and content attributes....the new variable is a product feature that was launched 2 months ago...so don't want to interpolate that over 2 years...